# Cannot get a simple freeglut test program to compile on windows

Tags: windows, opengl, freeglut

I downloaded the "Unofficial OpenGL Software SDK" which includes freeglut, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I am on Windows. I have not had success with either Visual Studio 2010 or MinGW g++. I have a very simple test program

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Test");

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Right now I am trying to compile it with

```
g++ -I/c/Libraries/usr/include -L/c/Libraries/usr/lib -lfreeglut
```

This is the error message I keep getting.

```
C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\cckeVUNm.o:gluttest.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\cckeVUNm.o:gluttest.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\cckeVUNm.o:gluttest.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\cckeVUNm.o:gluttest.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitDisplayMode@4'
C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\cckeVUNm.o:gluttest.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitWindowSize@8'
C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\cckeVUNm.o:gluttest.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `_imp__glutMainLoop@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know it can find the header file and the library file since if I delete either of the files, it gives me an error saying it cannot find them. I am not really sure where to go from here. I have tried recompiling freeglut, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Someone mentioned adding -DFREEGLUT_STATIC to let it know it was compiling statically. However, I got the same error message.

Any advice?

Based on answer so far I changed my compile command to

```
g++ gluttest.cpp -o gluttest -I/c/Libraries/glsdk_0.4.4/freeglut/include -L/c/Libraries/glsdk_0.4.4/freeglut/lib -DFREEGLUT_STATIC -D_LIB -DFREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS=0 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -luser32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lfreeglut
```

But am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually [link with the libraries](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_use.html). `-L` just sets the library path. Since you're not using the provided Premake4 tools to link with the library, you must also set the defines as listed in the instructions on the aforementioned page.

Comment: Based on what is in the instructions there, I changed the g++ command. I put it in an edit above.

But I am getting the same error.